# How can I serialize an object but have a given property remain serialized to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-core-webapi, uint8array

I have the following ASP.NET Core Controller:

```cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FightClubApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjectMayhemController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public Member Get() =>
            new Member
            {
                Name = "Robert Paulson",
                Code = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("His name was Robert Paulson")
            };
    }

    public class Member
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hitting that API endpoint (using `GET https://localhost:5001/api/ProjectMayhem`) returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Robert Paulson",
  "code": "SGlzIG5hbWUgd2FzIFJvYmVydCBQYXVsc29u"
}
```

However, I would like the `Member.Code` property to be serialized to a JavaScript `Uint8Array`.

I could convert the Base64 encoded JSON property back to a `Uint8Array` using something like:

```js
code = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(atob(code));
```

, but I want to avoid doing it on the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I can sort of do this if I make `Code` a list of bytes i.e.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FightClubApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjectMayhemController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public Member Get() => new Member
        {
            Name = "Robert Paulson",
            Code = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("His name was Robert Paulson")
                                      .ToList()
        };
    }

    public class Member
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<byte> Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hitting that API endpoint (using GET https://localhost:5001/api/ProjectMayhem) returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Robert Paulson",
  "code": [
    72, 105, 115, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 119, 97, 115, 32, 82, 111, 98, 101, 114, 116, 32, 80, 97, 117, 108, 115, 111, 110
  ]
}
```

I would just need to cast it to an `Uint8Array`.